# Python: How to save files from folders and subfolders?

Tags: python

I have a main folder: `e:\\PLUS`, which contains another 4 subfolders (`A,B,C,D`). Now, my python code saves all the html files from the main folder (`PLUS`) but doesn't save the files from the other 4 subfolders.

Can anyone update my code a little bit, so as to save the files also from the subfolders?

```
def check_links_for_all_files(directory_name):
    for file in os.listdir(directory_name):
        filename = str(file)
        print(filename)
        
        if filename.endswith(".html"): #or filename.endswith(".php"):
            file_path = os.path.join(directory_name, filename)
            
            check_link(file_path)
        else:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_links_for_all_files("e:\\Plus")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module. It belongs to the python standard library as well, and, in my opinion, it may be a bit more intuitive to use than the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module.

```py
import pathlib

def check_links_for_all_files(directory_name):
    directories = [pathlib.Path(directory_name)]
    for directory in directories:
        for file in directory.iterdir():
            if file.is_dir():
                directories.append(file)
                continue
            print(file.name)
            if file.suffix == '.html':
                check_link(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the main directory, but not going into sub-directories.
Try using `os.path.isdir` to handle the sub-directories.

Could do something like this:

```
def check_links_for_all_files(directory_name):
    for file in os.listdir(directory_name):
        path = os.path.join(directory_name, str(file))
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            check_links_for_all_files(path)
        
        if path.endswith(".html"): #or filename.endswith(".php"):
            check_link(path)
        else:
            continue
```

Notice this will handle the entire directory tree and not just the first hop into the sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

os.walk is very efficient to iterate over all files and subfolders, here is an example:

```
import os
    
def check_links_for_all_files(directory_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_name):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".html"):  # or file.endswith(".php"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                check_link(file_path)
            else:
                continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_links_for_all_files("/Users/hbohra/Downloads/")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os

def check_links_for_all_files(directory_name):
  for file_path in glob.glob(
      os.path.join(directory_name, '**', '*.html'),recursive=True):
    check_link(file_path)
```